# C# need to store a parsed version of SQL Server table, use datatable or list

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, datagridview

I'm new to C#.  I know that datatable is very efficient for reading an entire SQL table and outputting data to griddataview.  However I need to do some parsing before storing the data in my griddataview.  I was thinking reading the table row by row and grouping the data when applicable.  Would a datatable or a list be more applicable in my case?

```
ORIGINAL TABLE                    PARSED TABLE I need to pass to datagridview
Name    Workdate                  Name     M T W TH F SAT SUN
Nicole     WED                    Nicole   Y   Y  Y
Nicole     THR                    Jason      Y
Nicole     MON
Jason      Tue
```

Comment: Datatable or List is not really relevant since you need to transform your data regardless. If you won't be doing CRUD on the data it is less efficient to use DataTable because it has a lot of functionality around change tracking that you wouldn't need.

Comment: @Crowcoder I am doing CRUD but I need to do a conversion each time from original table format to my format.

Comment: I don't see how you would make changes to that grid and get them sent back to the database without an intermediate step that unpivots it.

Comment: I wrote an article 7 years ago, that show you how to pivot client side: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/796651/Client-Side-Multi-Column-Dynamic-Pivot

Comment: @JesúsLópez Thanks for the tip.  I can also write a stored procedure to pivot server side vs doing it in C# would server side be better?

Comment: @bakalolo, as the article says server side dynamic pivot is complex, that SQL dynamic code seems very awful to me . If possible, I always prefer pivoting in c# or even in angular. I believe that pivoting is a presentation layer concern not a database concern.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                {"MON", "M"},{"TUE", "T"},{"WED", "W"},{"THR", "TH"},{"FRI", "F"},{"SAT", "SAT"},{"SUN", "SUN"}};
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Workdate", typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Nicole", "WED" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Nicole", "THR" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Nicole", "MON" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Jason", "TUE" });

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
            pivot.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
            DataColumn[] columns = dict.Select(x => new DataColumn(x.Value, typeof(string))).ToArray();
            pivot.Columns.AddRange(columns);

            var people = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Name")).ToArray();
            foreach (var person in people)
            {
                DataRow pivotRow = pivot.Rows.Add();
                pivotRow["Name"] = person.Key;
                foreach (DataRow row in person)
                {
                    string day = row.Field<string>("Workdate");
                    pivotRow[dict[day]] = "Y";
                 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```